# Is there a way to see a list of all bookmarks in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I wonder if there is a way to see all the bookmarks in the project in a list?

Some way similar to **Debug > Windows > Breakpoints** give us all the breakpoints.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, the option is available under **View** -> **Bookmark Window** option.

[image: Bookmark window]

Or the keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> to see the bookmark window.

<sub>Note: I can confirm the same setting is applicable for Visual Studio Professional 2017, Community 2017.</sub>

Comment: IN VS2019 Community it's under: View > Other Windows > Bookmark Window

Comment: A bit surprised that it's not in the sub menu of: Edit > Bookmarks.

Comment: in vs2022 it's the same as 2017

Comment: Tip: To Jump through single Bookmarks you can use:
1) To Next : Ctrl+K+N
2) To Previous : Ctrl+K+P

Or the icons on the top of the Bookmarks Window